# attribute cannot be resolved as a member of bean (JSF)

Tags: jsf, el

Hello i keep getting this warning for 4 attributes.

the one in the .xhtml is

```
First Name : <h:inputText value="#{projectBean.fname}" id="fname" required="true" requiredMessage="   Firstname is required"></h:inputText>
    <h:message for="fname" styleClass="error"></h:message>
```

and the one in the bean is

```
private String fname;

public String getfName() {
    return fname;
}
public void setfName(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
```

the warning im getting

> fname cannot be resolved as a member of projectBean

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Where do you get the warnings? Runtime? In your IDE? In your dreams? ( ;-) ) And try to post the error in a search engine and look for the generic issue... And what if you run the project? Other errors?

Comment: Like Kukeltje said in the previous comments the naming convention is wrong. Try `getFName`/`setFName`. If this doesn't work try using `#{projectBean.getFName()}`

Comment: @fuggerjaki61: getFname/setFname ;-)